# still got the ssh asking for password too many times and then fail the connection

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

vscode ssh remote extension by microsoft.
I can ssh to the machine just fine, but can't vscode ssh to it.
log code https://justpaste.it/be7wz

i try all method, including delete the lock file.
it was just working fine this morning, until some body else logged in. does vscode remote ssh only support one user at a time.

Comment: In the log you provided, there is a reference to a lock file: "Waiting for lock /var/run/nologin or /run/nologin." This lock file could be preventing new SSH connections. Ensure that this file is not locked by another process or user. You can try to remove it if it's not needed. Depending on the operating system and system configuration, there may be user session limits in place. Check with your system administrator or review system limits Sometimes, restarting the SSH service on the remote machine can resolve connection issues.

Comment: i couldn't search this text "Waiting for lock /var/run/nologin or /run/nologin." Are you sure that string is in my lock file?

Answer (score 0):

Source:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

**Installation**

1. Install an [OpenSSH compatible SSH client](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_installing-a-supported-ssh-client).
2. If you do not have a SSH host set up, follow the directions for [Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_installing-a-supported-ssh-server), [Windows 10 / Server (1803+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui), or [macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui) or create a [VM on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json&tabs=ubuntu).

**Getting Started**
Follow the [step-by-step tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial) or if you have a simple SSH host setup, connect to it as follows:

1. Press F1 and run the Remote-SSH: Open SSH Host... command.
2. Enter your user and host/IP in the following format in the input box that appears and press enter: user@host-or-ip or user@domain@host-or-ip
3. If prompted, enter your password (but we suggest setting up [key based authentication](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_configuring-key-based-authentication)).
4. After you are connected, use File > Open Folder to open a folder on the host.
   You can press F1 to bring up the Command Palette and type in Remote-SSH for a full list of available commands.

Comment: your answer does not target the question